# Directly use the result of a custom less function

Tags: less

as a Software Developer I'm used to reuse my code instead of stupid copy&paste work.

In my Less-File, i want to compute a complementary color multiple times and use it e.g. for text color.

so i defined my function like this:

```
.getComplement(@baseColor){
    @invertedColor: #fff - @baseColor;
    return: @invertedColor;
}
```

with this i tried to use the outcome of the function like this:

```
.classSelector {
    color: .getComplement(#000);
}
```

But when compiling it, the compiler always says "Syntax Error" on the line where i use the function and set the color:

```
color: .getComplement(#000);
```

so my question is, how can i directly use the output of a function in LESS like it can be done with e.g.

```
color: darken(red, 10%);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are defining is a parametric mixin, which is not technically a function (though it has aspects that are function like). The functions are all inbuilt in LESS (you cannot really define your own function unless you modify the LESS source code). Therefore, you cannot use a mixin to set a property *value* only. You can only use it to either set the property itself to a value (as Jonathan's answer does), or set the variable you wish to use, like this:

```
.getComplement(@baseColor){
    @invertedColor: #fff - @baseColor;
}

.classSelector {
    .getComplement(#f00);
    color: @invertedColor;
}
```

Produces this css:

```
.classSelector {
  color: #00ffff;
}
```

This will allow some flexibility to use it in multiple places, like this:

```
.classSelector2 {
    .getComplement(#f00);
    background-color: @invertedColor;  
}
```

But *will not work twice in the same selector*, because of the lazy loading style of LESS variables. So this will use the second value for both:

```
.classSelector {
    .getComplement(#f00);
    color: @invertedColor;
    .getComplement(#00f); // This will be used for both
    background-color: @invertedColor;  
}
```

CSS Output

```
.classSelector {
  color: #00ffff; // Note this is the value of the 2nd call to .getComplement()
  background-color: #00ffff;
}
```

Two possible work arounds for that are:

**(1) Nest a selector block** (this has the downside of duplicate css output)

```
.classSelector {
    .getComplement(#f00);
    color: @invertedColor;

    & {
    .getComplement(#00f);
    background-color: @invertedColor;
    }
}
```

CSS output

```
.classSelector {
  color: #00ffff;
}
.classSelector {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

**(2) Add some extra variables to output in the mixin** (downside is larger mixin and some variables may go unused at times)

```
.getComplement(@baseColor, @ext:'C') {
    .returnColor(C) {
       @invertedColor: #fff - @baseColor;
    }
    .returnColor(B) {
       @invertedBkgColor: #fff - @baseColor;
    }
    .returnColor(@ext);
}

.classSelector {
    .getComplement(#f00);
    color: @invertedColor;
    .getComplement(#00f, B);
    background-color: @invertedBkgColor;
}
```

Produces this combined and correct css:

```
.classSelector {
  color: #00ffff;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

There may be a few other creative ways to make the mixin usable more than once within a selector block, but those are the two that came to mind first.

Comment: There's a [third method](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7875513#file-20468332-less) (sort of modified #1), which optionally can be reformatted to something [like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7875696#file-2046833-4-less).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Ah yes, nesting a mixin in the selector itself. I don't know why I didn't think of that, but good added comment.

Comment: I did not too before I saw your #2. I guess that's just because we usually stop at #1 (which is acceptable in most cases :)

Comment: thanks for this. now i know at least that what i want to do cannot be achieved withoud modifing the less source code. the 3 options you presented here, may help others :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be as the function becomes the css variable and value

```
.getComplement(@baseColor){
    color: #fff - @baseColor;
}

.classSelector {
    .getComplement(#000);
}
```

Comment: but what if i want to use the computed color as background color at another element too? So, this is not a solution :)

Comment: I am not sure you can do that in LESS, would one of the inbuilt functions not work for you http://lesscss.org/#reference

Comment: unfortunately, less does not offer a function to calculate the inverse /complementary of a color. that's why i have to write my own.